# In Mono/Gnome, how can I look up the icon for a mime type?

Tags: c#, mono, mime-types, gnome

Gnome.Icon and Gnome.ThumbnailFactory both want me to pass in a URI of a file whose icon I want -- I only have a MIME type, which I want to look up an icon for.  Is there a GNOME C# API function which will give me what I want?  Ideally the prototype would just be:

Gdk.Pixbuf LookupIcon (string mime_type);

Answer (score 3):

Here's MonoDevelop's code to do this:

[MonoDevelop SVN](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/monodevelop/main/src/addins/GnomePlatform/GnomePlatform.cs?view=markup)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but it appears that this code is looking up icons for particular files, rather than MIME types -- the question was about how to get an icon for a mime type even without a file.